# Issue with global variable when passing into another if statment

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am trying to get Ardinput to pass into the `if "(Ardinput == stagecode):"` but it seems like Ardinput loses it's contents

here is my output for the code

```
Start capture
b'STAGE\r\n'
STAGE
 Befor CR
STAGE
```

Code:

```
url = config.url()

stagecode = "STAGE "

ser = serial.Serial(
 port='COM3',
 baudrate=9600, 
)

def stage():
    urllib.request.urlopen(url + 'f.stage')

def capture():
    global Ardinput
    print ("Start capture")
    while (1):           
        line = ser.readline()
        if (line != ""):
            print (line)
            Ardinput = line
            Ardinput = Ardinput.decode("utf-8")
            print (Ardinput + ' Befor CR')
            Ardinput = Ardinput[:-1]
            print (Ardinput)
            if (Ardinput == stagecode):       
                print (stagecode + ' IN IF FUNCTION')
                stage()
capture()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed just the `\n` newline but left the `\r` carriage return in place.

Use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) instead to remove *all* whitespace from start and end:

```
Ardinput = line.decode('utf8').strip()
```

and remove the space from `stagecode`:

```
stagecode = "STAGE"
```

For future reference, it is far easier to spot these differences if you use the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) or even [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) functions to produce a string literal version of the value:

```
>>> line = b'STAGE\r\n'
>>> Ardinput = line.decode('utf8')[:-1]
>>> print(Ardinput)
STAGE
>>> print(repr(Ardinput))
'STAGE\r'
```

Note how the latter shows that there is still a `\r` carriage return character in the value.

`\r` and `\n` are considered whitespace, as are spaces and tabs and the [non-break space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

```
>>> '\t\t   Hello world!  \xa0\r\n'.strip()
'Hello world!'
```

Note that the space in the middle was not removed; `str.strip()` works on the lead and trail ends of a string only.

Comment: Wow also thank you for shorting my function with Ardinput = line.decode('utf8').strip()! Very handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

`\r\n` represents a carriage return with a new line (hence:

```
STAGE
Befor CR
```

and not `STAGE Befor CR`). You will have to strip it for instance with  `Ardinput.decode('utf-8').strip()` to remove the newline, or remove the last 2 characters with `Ardinput.decode('utf-8')[:-2]`).

Comment: I cannot believe Ardinput = Ardinput[:-1 ] was the problem. I added 2 there and it all worked, Great work thank you!